# React - slide down menu reveal menu items on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to add a dropdown menu slide down that slowly reveals the menu items.  I am using `CSSTransition` from `react-transition-group`.  I have the blue background doing the nice slow slidedown that I want.  But the text items just instantly shows up.  Here is my codesandbox showing the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-dawn-zbmt5

My Navbar component:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [showSchedDropdown, setShowSchedDropdown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ul className={"nav"}>
      <li
        className={"nav-item dropdown"}
        onMouseEnter={() => setShowSchedDropdown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShowSchedDropdown(false)}
      >
        <button
          className={"nav-link dropdown-toggle"}
          aria-haspopup={"true"}
          aria-expanded={"false"}
          onClick={() => setShowSchedDropdown(true)}
        >
          Dropdown Menu
        </button>
        <CSSTransition
          in={showSchedDropdown}
          timeout={1300}
          classNames={"hidden-menu"}
        >
          <div className={"dropdown-menu"}>
            {showSchedDropdown && (
              <>
                <Link
                  className={"dropdown-item"}
                  to={"/baglines"}
                  onClick={() => setShowSchedDropdown(false)}
                >
                  Menu Item 1
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className={"dropdown-item"}
                  to={"/totelines"}
                  onClick={() => setShowSchedDropdown(false)}
                >
                  Menu Item 2
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className={"dropdown-item"}
                  to={"/otherlines"}
                  onClick={() => setShowSchedDropdown(false)}
                >
                  Menu Item 3
                </Link>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And the CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(#265077, 1);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: none;
  transition: height 1.3s ease;

  &.hidden-menu-enter,
  &.hidden-menu-exit-done {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1.3s ease;
  }

  &.hidden-menu-enter-active {
    height: 100px;
    transition: height 1.3s ease;
  }

  &.hidden-menu-enter-done {
    height: 100px;
  }

  &.hidden-menu-leave {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1.3s ease;
  }

  &.hidden-menu-leave-active {
    height: 100px;
    transition: height 1.3s ease;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Your child menu is recreated each time on hover/hover out 2. Once you sorted point 1, set `overflow: hidden` for `.dropdown-menu` element

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info?  How do you know it is being recreated?  Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: It is because the state is updated each time on mouse enter/leave and this line `{showSchedDropdown && (` is preventing your child menu from rendering. The bad thing in your case is that there is nothing to animate when the mouse enter the menu, hence your child menu is not animated.

Comment: OK, figured it out with your comments!  Removed the conditional `showSchedDropdown` code and have it always on the page with height of 0.  New class changes the height and it works beautifully!  You can add an answer if you like, and I will accept.